# Hddtemp and drivers

Tags: linux, centos, dell, smart

```
hddtemp /dev/sda
/dev/sda: DELL PERC 6/i Adapter: S.M.A.R.T. not available
```

Does this mean I need to install some type of driver on my linux server to access that information?

Answer (score 2):

For disks behind RAID controllers like the PERC, SMART data is not available in the same way as for "normal" disks and require special support from the SMART client. My guess is that `hddtemp` doesn't offer this support.

Try [`smartmontools`](http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net/) instead, they [officially support](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/smartmontools/wiki/Supported_RAID-Controllers) this LSI/Dell controller model to get the data.